# Question on Pairing users by Attributes.. Algorithm/Data Structure

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I have a question on algorithm that I am stuck in.

> We are given a sequence of users, and
>   set of attributes for each user. As
>   soon as we read a user, we should pair
>   it with another previously read user
>   with identical attributes who is
>   currently unpaired, if such a user
>   exists.
>
> If the user cannot be paired, we
>   should keep that user in the unpaired
>   set.
>
> **The QUESTIONS are,**
>
> > 1. How would we implement this matching process efficiently...
> > 2. How would we implement it if we allow an approximate match of
> >        attributes as well...

The solution to first question, I found is using trie data-structure, wherein we arrange the attributes of each user in sorted order and start inserting the atttributes into the trie, with user attached to the leaf. If a new user comes in, we follow the same trie and if we found previous user attached to the leaf, then we found the pair or else we insert that new user into the leaf.

Kindly suggest your idea or any new thought on this solution and kindly help me in solving the second question. I am completely clueless in 2nd question..

Explanation with some sample codes or an example would be helpful..

Thanks...

Comment: Define approximate match of attributes.

Comment: any approximate match lets say k attributes should match..........

Answer (score 2):

Hash table of all unpaired users, key = user attribute.

When use enters, and is assigned the attribute, lookup him in the hash.

If found, then he is paired. Remove the 2nd (paired user) use from hash.
Do not add just entered user to th hash.

If not found, add him to the hash (he is awating his pair).

Done

Comment: If there are N users and each user has M attributes, isn't this O(M*(N^2))? The worst case being none of the N users get paired. Can we do better?